# Vue/Vuex/GSAP-Animation: Add DOM elements to store

Tags: dom, vue.js, vuex, gsap

In a Vue project, I am looking for a way to save DOM elements to the store. Those elements shall then be animated with GSAP.

Unfortunately, there is a bit of a problem with when the DOM is ready (so I can use document.querySelector) and when Vue's transition system is firing.

the store has about this structure:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        settings: {
            ui: {
               btns: {
                   cBtnNavMain: {
                       el: document.querySelector('.c-btn__nav--main') // does not work, because DOM is not yet ready
                       [...]
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        // Add DOM element later via a mutation?
        addDomElementToStore: (state, obj) => {
            console.log("MUTATION addDomElementToStore, obj =", obj) // shows `null`
            obj.el = obj.domEl  
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in App.vue (loaded by main.js) there is basically this script:

```
created() {
    console.log("App.vue created")
}
mounted() {
    console.log("App.vue created")
}
methods: {
    beforeEnter(el) {
        console.log("BeforeEnter called, obj")

        // This could be the place to add DOM to the store, but how?
        // I tried a mutations like this (see above in store.mutations):
        this.$store.commit('addDomElementToSettings', {
           el: this.$store.state.settings.ui.btns.cNavMainBtn.el,
           domEl: document.querySelector('.c-btn__nav--main')
        })
        // ...but won't work though, the console shows, obj params are empty
    }
    [...]
}
```

The console result shows something like this:

```
App.vue created
BeforeEnter called // <-- beginEnter before mounted called!
MUTATION addDomElementToStore, obj = {el: null, domElem: null}
App.vue mounted
```

Since "beforeEnter" is called after created, but BEFORE mounted (which is, where the DOM would be easily accessible), the DOM is not really accessible yet, it seems. So I thought, I use "beforeEnter" to assign new DOM elements to store.settings using a mutation. But that doesn't work at all - and GSAP eventually has do DOM elements to animate on.

What do I have to do to get my DOM elements saves to the settings, so that I do not have to use `document.querySelector` all the time, when I want to address a DOM element with GSAP?

Comment: Try wrapping it in `$nextTick()` which should defer processing of the function until the next DOM update.

Comment: That could be a way. But then I wonder: what will the consequences be, when every event has to be "moved" by a tick? And maybe later other events have to be moved to the next tick again? I will try. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try you using the `mounted()` lifecycle method to fire the mutation that stores DOM element selections in vuex state? That way you know something exists to select.

Comment: I cannot do that, because, as I explained in my post, Vue's transition system fires before that. And I need the elements by then already. – It seems I need to wrap the whole app in a <transition-group/> and add various transition components...

Comment: I guess I don't understand your use case. Seems like a strange thing to add DOM to the state instead of using the  transitions Vue has available. Couldn't you animate these DOM elements as individual components and then dynamically add them into an existing layout?

Comment: I totally agree that it is strange, and I hope, it is all a big misunderstanding on my side. But currently the problem is, that there are components that are outside of the transition component, but need to be triggered, as soon as a transition hook (like beforeEnter or enter) gets active. "beforeEnter" and "enter" both fire in BEFORE Vue's mounted(), which means, the DOM is not yet available to GSAP. And since there are animations that need to finish first, before done() is called, it is necessary for TweenMax to set some values, before the anim starts...

Comment: I try setting up an example on CodePen and report back. (But I struggle quite a bit to cut it down to the minimum...)